Linux command line utilities: Can sort(1) sort text by multiple (>2) columns?
I have the following data
foo-a12a11
foo-a12a2
foo-a12b12
foo-a12b21
foo-a13a10
foo-a13a1
foo-a13a9
IIII122344      # this indicates the order in which I want to consider the fields (I=ignore)

I want to sort it first by the single letter, then by the first number, then by the letter, then finally by the trailing number in numerical order.
From reading the man page of sort I thought this would be enough sort --key=1.1db,2.8n. But this returns sort: options '-dn' are incompatible ... which I find odd as I thought they should be treated as spearate keys.
Trying to switch the second key to sort with d works, but sorts the trailing number in lexicographic order (i.e. 10 is placed before 9)
Anyone know how I achieve my desired sort (shown below, manually produced)?:
foo-a12a2
foo-a12a11
foo-a12b12
foo-a12b21
foo-a13a1
foo-a13a9
foo-a13a10

The foo-a is currently the same in all cases, so I've chosen to ignore it for purposes of sorting.

why 2.8? there's only one field. Is every section fixed width except the second number?

It is fixed width, but I want it sort by the first number first, then move on to the a/b/c etc, then finally the trailing number.
Have I missed something?

This question belongs on [unix.se], as it is about shell utilities and not about programming.

@KenWhite Sorry - I followed the search from Unix, and assumed i was in the right place.

@user9793038: NP. Happens all the time. A lot of users (even ones that are experienced here) are not aware of some of the other [se] sites.

With fixed-width sections as shown (and assuming no blank characters), you could try:
sort -k 1.5db,1.5 -k 1.6n,1.7 -k 1.8db,1.8 -k 1.9n


Oh.... multiple options. I saw that --key took comma-separated, so assumed that was the only method to do its hierarchy...
Thanks, I think that's perfect.

(Edit:) @user9793038 :  "I saw that --key took comma-separated" ... The comma is used to delimit the ending part (2nd half) of one particular key, NOT as a way to add multiple sections of input as keys. This is the extended form of key defs as opposed to "std", -k1 -k3 -k2 using whole fields of data for keys.  The multiple use of -k is the correct way to "sort text my multiple (>2) columns". Note also in the above how the comma IS used, that it is "picking out" specific range of characters from a "word". 1.6n,1.7 being the most obvious example, think of it as 1.6-1.7(n). Good Luck.

@shellter I'm not sure -k1 -k3 -k2 will ever give different output than -k1. I think you need at least -k1,1 -k3 -k2 (and probably -k1,1 -k3,3 -k2). without the comma I think -k compares up to end of line (try looking at what is compared using GNU sort's --debug option)

@jhnc : I didn't have space or think the OP was ready for -t\t' numbering of fields. (-; Yea, with no -tX option, it wouldn't be sorting by numbered fields. Might not (in this example) be that -k2 is the last seen, last processed? I run a test sometime, busy now. Good luck to all.

@shellter "When there are multiple key fields, later keys shall be compared only after all earlier keys compare equal" - -k1 compares the entire line (ignoring leading whitespace in absence of -t) so the only time -k3 or -k2 would get used is when they would do nothing (if A==B, tail(A)==tail(B))
